# Is there a formula to calculate the number of working days for different tasks broken down monthly with specific month start and end date?(see image))

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I tried `NETWORKDAYS( )` formula but am facing issues to break down the days monthly based on the specific months start and end dates: for example, I tried in `F3`: `=NETWORKDAYS(B3,F2)`.

I need a formula which can capture all my conditions (working days between B and C split monthly as per start end dates defined in columns E to P) and be used in all the cells highlighted in yellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using <kbd>NETWORKDAYS( )</kbd> function by hybridizing it with <kbd>MAX( )</kbd> & <kbd>MIN( )</kbd> function within it.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E3</kbd>

```
=MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS(MAX($B3,E$1),MIN($C3,E$2)))
```

---

Ofcourse, the formula needs to fill down and fill right.

---

You can also use one single dynamic array formula to spill the resilts, i.e. using <kbd>MAKEARRAY( )</kbd> function provided you are using **MS365**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E3</kbd>

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(B3:C6),COLUMNS(E1:P2),LAMBDA(r,c,
           MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS(
           MAX(INDEX(B3:C6,r,1),INDEX(E1:P2,1,c)),
           MIN(INDEX(B3:C6,r,2),INDEX(E1:P2,2,c))))))
```

---

To hide the `0`s i have used custom formatting as : `0;;`

---

To have clear readability you can define variables using <kbd>LET( )</kbd> function

```
=LET(
     _taskStart,B3:B6,
     _taskEnd,C3:C6,
     _monthStart,E1:P1,
     _monthEnd,E2:P2,
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_taskStart),COLUMNS(_monthStart),LAMBDA(r,c,
     MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS(MAX(INDEX(_taskStart,r),INDEX(_monthStart,c)),
     MIN(INDEX(_taskEnd,r),INDEX(_monthEnd,c)))))))
```

---

[image]

---

Comment: Great, Many thanks, this is what I needed. I think it will work wonderfully for me

Comment: Absolutely Sounds Good =)